# Minor UI request - add icons to "hot questions"

Tags: feature-request

In the dropdown in the upper-right, I really like the icons used for "inbox" to differentiate the sites.

[image: inbox example]

Any chance you could show those icons for "hot questions" as well, in the same place?

I realize that information *(what site the question is for)* is already available, but that's not the point - they're just visually pleasing.  There's room on the left, above the rating, if you move the rating down a bit.

[image: hot questions example]